# How can I get yesterday without calling moment twice?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, dayofweek, days

I can get the `moment` object for yesterday by calling

```
var yesterday = moment().day(moment.day()-1);
```

But this requires me to call `moment` twice, and that bugs me. Is there a way to achieve the same end using `moment`'s API only once?

Comment: `var yesterday = moment().day(((new Date).getDay()) - 1);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
moment().subtract(1, 'days');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `moment().subtract(1, 'days');`

More examples [here](http://momentjs.com/).